# Find and replace URLs in postfix files - Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: bash, perl, ubuntu, sed, postfix-mta

I want to monitor a specific folder.
Every new file in this folder should be scanned for URLs.
These URLs should be edited, if the domain is not in a defined whitelist.

Example:

```
blabla http://www.black.com/green/yellow.html blabla
sdfsdfsdfsdf http://www.white.com/red.html
```

Whitelist:

```
http://www.white.com
```

Result:

```
blabla httx://www.black.com/green/yellow.html blabla
sdfsdfsdfsdf http://www.white.com/red.html
```

What i have tried so far is iwatch with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM "/etc/iwatch/iwatch.dtd" >
<config>
  <guard email="root@localhost" name="IWatch"/>
  <watchlist>
    <title>URL_Filter</title>
    <contactpoint email="admin@test.com" name="Administrator"/>
    <path type="single" syslog="on" alert="off" events="create" exec="sed -i 's/http/httx' %f">/var/test</path>
  </watchlist>
</config>
```

So with iwatch i can observe the folder "/var/test" for new files.
With the sed command i can replace every "http" with "httx".
But i have no idea how i could put in a whitelist so that some URLs are not replaced...

--- edit ---
Additional information: 
I want to edit all incoming postfix mails, so that there are no clickable links in it, except some domains, which are on the whitelist. The reason for that is to protect against phishing mails.

```
Return-Path: <example@gmail.com>
X-Original-To: example@test.de
Delivered-To: example@test.de
Received: from mail-lf0-x236.google.com (mail-lf0-x236.google.com [IPv6:2a00:1450:4010:c07::236])
        by xxxxxxx.hosteurope.de (Postfix) with ESMTPS id D255223CB59
        for <example@test.de>; Mon, 11 Apr 2016 14:44:10 +0200 (CEST)
Received: by mail-lf0-x236.google.com with SMTP id c126so154788483lfb.2
        for <example@test.de>; Mon, 11 Apr 2016 05:39:20 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to;
        bh=WwH+NIkCWDEoIkwbeCI4pf0jP0ya/ctbQ81pUsA4G7s=;
        b=ZS3Uo/cpVGNw3k38Js2+/DxVda0y2136oy4D4hsR0G25x2UjhyVU/yUcPl6qEdxt8i
         CQXZHQbaf8pzCdDaSq4VL9RC/sIgZy3PQzj6Cyrp3WTi6SMmQ65NwNBWLVGnpPcuzNW1
         IGC5N3rjj96ndYUAxia/tTcBX7ajS3Tw9Mc8yIaO13hSXMUCrTDIFZNzHR1ib7tLDpmX
         6EVyFhquhIfJVOhcuPgWUUxHly/FmZ++ucoHR0Yozj+dc1GJ6/ZYzUAPdGICelDY7ieG
         nvA7KH6+v6/zoWlbfkO9BmGzAPs6M4LGHilOjpMf/09Z2oMiV/WRDxe0WrCebQptpm2c
         xHPg==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to;
        bh=WwH+NIkCWDEoIkwbeCI4pf0jP0ya/ctbQ81pUsA4G7s=;
        b=hAOSzKjertcsQIT/PHoZKsiKxLba8gaKOCmyNg7nmiPJjCWqobNvM5nf3sZP1Xhysi
         gGdvk9mmMugII8dsjc7mRhDkbCT1QKVz/0UBQ+CaP6sK7kGdWfdarphGgzUGA6Il5JZi
         lP4DpEQHUpG1wJ1r+dN2f+UT8tyfIwapXwo3g7FnkPLxmCq9CeqJeRlagL6vAacon8z7
         CjdTHB7fzEtYToSp+cDi3+yK4zS9p4rwF4H4Ds3bJqwM/PrcFJW0YYncDHdra5TwYf6U
         K6VRX19iUhQT4kTVFCtoNW9SU8Ri+Rc5VfvVTKRh4KwZ2uW5x8y07ucB0vZcAQdEnms4
         AWnQ==
X-Gm-Message-State: AD7BkJJEDmk9P+Kzcn1MT4lQxpU1aYU6x8uABSpohCbT7EeOFAXjT1y6n3sFcRj7tcfWc6eBAOL6bJ78jvVOlQ==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.112.63.196 with SMTP id i4mr8426739lbs.93.1460378359811;
 Mon, 11 Apr 2016 05:39:19 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.114.66.51 with HTTP; Mon, 11 Apr 2016 05:39:19 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 14:39:19 +0200
Message-ID: <CADF5gVU+C4BZCSFSiWeiBipBnDu5jTU+FVmLJbSQSbtMM9JZcQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
From: Example <example@gmail.com>
To: example@test.de
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1133d4405fd878053034d55a
X-Scanned-By: MIMEDefang 2.71 on 5.38.258.144

--001a1133d4405fd878053034d55a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

http://www.example.com
http://www.white.com

--001a1133d4405fd878053034d55a
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr"><div><a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a><br></div><a href="http://www.white.com">http://www.white.com</a><br></div>

--001a1133d4405fd878053034d55a--
```

Comment: Your example is pretty weird. Please tell us what you really want to do. Changing `http` to `httx` doesn't make sense. What kind of files are we talking about?

Comment: I want to edit all incoming postfix mails, so that there are no clickable links in it, except some domains, which are on the whitelist. The reason for that is to protect against phishing mails.

Comment: You can [edit] your question and add that detail. There is probably also a way to do that within postfix, or with some tool attached to it. I don't know about that though.

Comment: A note on your edit: On Stack Overflow it makes more sense to just change the question if you add information. No need to add an _edit_ section. Just clarify so new readers see the most recent version. The people who asked for the update know it from the comment anyway, and they can also always check the diff in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36543377/revisions), which you get by clicking the _edited n mins ago_. :)

Comment: Related follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592723/execute-bash-command-for-all-incoming-mails-postfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized the `bash` script is un-necessary, we can do it using the following **one-liner but it's really cryptic to read**:

Input data:

```
$ cat data
sdfsdfsdfsdf http://www.whitedomain.com/red.html
bla http://www.black.com/green/yellow.html blabla
sdfsdfsdfsdf http://www.white.com/red.html
$ cat whitelist 
http://www.white.com
http://www.whitedomain.com
$
```

**Final Output:**

```
$ sed -r '/'"$(sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g' whitelist | paste -s -d '|')"'/! s/http/httx/g' data
sdfsdfsdfsdf http://www.whitedomain.com/red.html
bla httx://www.black.com/green/yellow.html blabla
sdfsdfsdfsdf http://www.white.com/red.html
$
```

Explanation:

Output of inner subshell command is a regex(to filter out lines during `sed` substitution command)

```
$ sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g' whitelist | paste -s -d '|'
http:\/\/www\.white\.com|http:\/\/www\.whitedomain\.com
```

Flow:

1. form the regex dynamically using inner subshell command escaping all meta characters in `sed` and then piping it to `paste` to add alternations
2. Using the above output in the `sed` command to filter out lines not having any of the whitelist domains and using those lines for substitution of `http` into `httx`

Edit1:  Since `sed` is line oriented you will have to transform the data into lines of text like this:

```
$ cat data1 
<div dir="ltr"><div><a href="http://www.white.com">http://www.white.com</a><br></div><a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a><br></div>
$ cat whitelist 
http://www.white.com
http://www.whitedomain.com
$ sed 's/</\n</g' data1 | sed -r '/'"$(sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g' whitelist | paste -s -d '|')"'/! s/http/httx/g'

<div dir="ltr">
<div>
<a href="http://www.white.com">http://www.white.com
</a>
<br>
</div>
<a href="httx://www.example.com">httx://www.example.com
</a>
<br>
</div>
$
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks again. I have tried it. Unfortunately it does not work for html links like
 `<div dir="ltr"><div><a href="http://www.white.com">http://www.white.com</a><br></div><a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a><br></div>`

Comment: @BP20 since `sed` is line oriented you will have to transform data into lines 1st, edited the ans accordingly

Comment: Do you know how I can put that sed command in the iwatch.xml <path exec>? The quotation marks are a problem...

Comment: @BP20 yeah that would be a problem, i cant test iwatch so can you try to escape the double quotes in the command

Comment: It is a xml file so i can escape it with "&quot;" but it does not work with iwatch. Dont know why... It is running and I can see in syslog that the command is executed but the message file is not modified. If I execute the command it works, so it must be a problem with iwatch. So I have added another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592723/edit-incoming-mails-with-postfix-after-queue-content-filter

Comment: @BP20 since you accepted the answer .. so is the problem solved or not?

Comment: The problem of editing the files and replace "http" with "httx" (except domains on whitelist) is solved. But to execute it automatically on every incoming postfix mail is not solved..

Answer (score 3):

You can use Perl to do that. I recommend installing the Regexp::Common package from CPAN and using [Regexp::Common::URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::URI) to find the URIs, then maintain a whitelist of host names and check those. It's a bit long for a one-liner though.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common qw /URI/;

my %whitelist = (
    'http://www.white.com' => 1,
    'http://www.example.org' => 1,
);

while (my $line = <>) {
    MATCH: foreach my $match ($line =~ /($RE{URI}{HTTP})/g ){
        # check the whitelist
        next MATCH if grep { $match =~ /^$_/i } %whitelist;

        # no whitelist entry, replace
        my $match_updated = $match;
        $match_updated =~ s/^http/httx/;
        $line =~ s/$match/$match_updated/;
    }
    print $line;
}
```

Save that as something meaningful, maybe remove_phishing_links.pl in a directory that the iwatch thingy can access. I'm doing `~`, but I have no clue if that would work. Now you would call that in your iwatch file with something like this.

```
<path 
  type="single" 
  syslog="on" 
  alert="off" 
  events="create" 
  exec="perl -i ~/remove_phishing_links.pl %f">/var/test</path>
```

It will, just like the `sed` command, edit the file in `%f` in place. It reads line by line, finds http URIs, checks if they start with any of the whitelist entries, and if not, replaces the `http` with `httx`.

Note that this will not work for base64 encoded MIME emails, or if there are line breaks within the URIs.

If you don't wnat to install Regexp::Common, you can also borrow the [regular expression for URIs from the URI module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#PARSING-URIs-WITH-REGEXP) on CPAN and alter it to only find `https?`.

Comment: @BP20: What happens when you call it manually with an input file?

Comment: The same. The file is empty afterwards.

Comment: @BP20 it worked with the example data you provided. I guess you'll have to give more realistic examples. Did you install the Regexp::Common module?

Comment: I have installed the Regexp::Common module. I have added a postfix file to the question which is empty after running the script.

Comment: @BP20 ouch. That's a nice bug. We're not printing lines without matches... give me a moment to fix. - done.

Comment: Ahh,ok. Thanks. Will try tomorrow. Any idea what to do with line breaks in URIs?

Comment: @BP20 yes, you need to read the file in one go instead of doing it line by line.