# Execute bash command for all incoming mails (Postfix)

Tags: bash, postfix-mta

I want to execute a command on the body of every incoming postfix mail.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\n//g' /path-to/message-file | sed 's/</\n\</g'  | sed -r '/'"$(sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g' whitelist | paste -s -d '|')"'/! s/http/httx/g'
```

I think it could be possible with [Postfix After-Queue Content Filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter), but I don't know how to do it...

EDIT:

afterqueue.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Simple shell-based filter. It is meant to be invoked as follows:
#       /path/to/script -f sender recipients...

# Localize these. The -G option does nothing before Postfix 2.3.
INSPECT_DIR=/var/spool/filter
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail -G -i" # NEVER NEVER NEVER use "-t" here.

# Exit codes from <sysexits.h>
EX_TEMPFAIL=75
EX_UNAVAILABLE=69

# Clean up when done or when aborting.
trap "rm -f in.$$" 0 1 2 3 15

# Start processing.
cd $INSPECT_DIR || {
    echo $INSPECT_DIR does not exist; exit $EX_TEMPFAIL; }

cat >in.$$ || { 
   echo Cannot save mail to file; exit $EX_TEMPFAIL; }

# Specify your content filter here.
sh /path/to/remove_links.sh <in.$$

$SENDMAIL "$@" <in.$$

exit $?
```

remove_links.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\n//g' $1 | sed 's/</\n\</g'  | sed -r '/'"$(sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g' /path/to/whitelist | paste -s -d '|')"'/! s/http/httx/g'
```

It is working, if I call it by hand, but if I add it to the /etc/postfix/master.cf like this:

```
  # =============================================================
  # service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command
  #               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
  # =============================================================
  filter    unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
    flags=Rq user=filter null_sender=
    argv=/path/to/afterqueue.sh -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

there are no changes in the mail.
I get the following syslog:

```
Apr 13 15:14:08 rs211184 postfix/qmgr[7492]: 3FFDF23CB5F: from=<test@gmail.com>, size=4358, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 15:14:08 rs211184 postfix/pipe[7504]: 116E523CA8C: to=<example@example.de>, relay=filter, delay=0.2, delays=0.16/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via filter service)
Apr 13 15:14:08 rs211184 postfix/qmgr[7492]: 116E523CA8C: removed
Apr 13 15:14:08 rs211184 postfix-local[7522]: postfix-local: from=test@gmail.com, to=example@example.de, dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames
Apr 13 15:14:08 rs211184 postfix/pipe[7521]: 3FFDF23CB5F: to=<dsehlhoff@lcdev1.de>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Apr 13 15:14:08 rs211184 postfix/qmgr[7492]: 3FFDF23CB5F: removed
```

Comment: I see now; Stack Overflow provided this as a "linked" question -- dunno why, but it's all clearer now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543377/find-and-replace-urls-in-postfix-files-linux-ubuntu?lq=1

Comment: The permission denied is obviously not a programming error. The postfix user lacks write (or possibly even read) access to the directory you are trying to have it manipulate.

Comment: OK, I have solved the permission denied. But the filter still won't work, although there are no errors in syslog... see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect the message in a file, and oddly a static file name, but that's not how it works.  The message arrives on standard input.  Minimally, just remove `/path/to/message-file` -- but really, piping `sed` to `sed` is very often a mistake; you should refactor this to a single `sed` script (or Awk, or Python, or what have you).

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\n//g' -e 's/</\n\</g' |
# This is too convoluted, really!
sed -r '/'"$(sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g' whitelist |
paste -s -d '|')"'/! s/http/httx/g'
```

Comment: If I could understand what the whitelist stuff is supposed to do, it would probably not be too hard to convert all of this to a relatively simple script.  Looks like maybe it's time to move from `sed` to something a little bit more advanced; or maybe put the whitelist stuff in an external file which you update whenever you update the `whitelist`.

Comment: Like noted in the earlier question, any MIME encoding is sufficient to bypass your filter.  HTML is often quoted-printable encoded; you'll miss any URL which looks like `htt=\np://badsite.example.com` (where the `\n` is a physical line break in a quoted-printable body) or base64-encoded URL.

Comment: I have edited the question...
But the linebreaks like `htt=\np://badsite.example.com` are replaced with the first sed command...